# compare array to mysql column and find the unmatched items

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php comma seperated string 
`$string = (x,y,z)`

I have a column in mysql that has items (y,z)

how do i compare the two and echo which items in $string are not in the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to compute differente in two comma separated strings.

Just convert your strings in to array using `explode` and use `array_diff`

`array_diff` -  Computes the difference of arrays

Example :

```
<?php

$array1=explode(",",$string);
$array2=explode(",",$yourstring_of_db_column);
$array1 = array("x", "y", "z");
$array2 = array( "y","z");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Be aware Values are compared using ===, so 1 and "1" are considered different.

Answer (score 1):

I think that should do the trick. Good Luck.

```
$myString="v1,v2,v3";
$stringA=explode(",",$myString);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$data=$row['dataColumn'];
if (!in_array($data,$stringA)) echo $data . "<br>";
}//end while
```

If you have data that needs to be exploded in the column we can go deeper.

```
$myString="v1,v2,v3";
$stringA=explode(",",$myString);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$data=$row['dataColumn'];
$da=explode(",",$data);
foreach($da as $value) if (!in_array($value,$stringA)) echo $data . "<br>";
}//end while
```

Comment: There's rarely a good reason for doing `SELECT * FROM data`. If the goal is to check the value of one column, it would  be good to select only that column. It's also good to consider only fetching data for the rows that need to be tested instead of the whole table.

Comment: Yeah I know this. I'm just used to doing it this way.

Comment: Just pointing this out for the benefit of the OP since it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

the logic behind this is first explode the string with the `explode(", ", $string)` function.
So that it will become an array.

And on the other hand check the value with the function `in_array()`,

For example:

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}
//output : 'ph' was found
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to compare with data stored in MySQL.

Comment: @MichaelMior i just clear the logic, because the asker didn't provide any code,

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about nested arrays. You might consider simplifying your example.

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this with one query, retrieving just the rows that do not match, eg.:

```
$string= "(str1, str2, str3)"; //formatted as the OP indicated
$input = explode(",",trim($string,"() "));
$filter = "(".$input[1].",".$input[2].")";

$sql = "select interestingColumn from greatTable where interestingColumn not like '".$filter."'";
$rez = mysql_query($sql);
while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($rez)){
     echo $row["interestingColumn"]."<br>\n";
}
```

this has the added benefit of retrieving fewer results from the database, which is desirable  especially if you have a large dataset

edit : fixed a typo on the second line (thanks Michael)

Comment: @Bogan The stuff in `$filter` needs to be quoted and potentially escaped. You also have several syntax errors on the second line.

Comment: yes, obviously you need to filter your data and make it secure, i was trying a barebones implementation to show the general idea (didn't run the code, so syntax errors are probable)